# switch DataContext according to departmentID

Tags: sql, datacontext

My company has 2 departments which sell air tickets to different categories of customers.
the two departments' ticket database are different but the tables inside them are identical.

I want to in insert row of data or manipulate data according to departmentID. In the old time, I can use a variable, departmentID, to determine which department and connect to the right database. And since tables structure are identical, the rest of the code can be shared.
example:  SQLstr = ".... from eAirsTable " + departmentID + "  where ..."

But now I'm DataContext and I have no idea how to do it.

```
    public class eAirs_OrderManager : IOrderInterface
    {
        public void Insert_OrderDB( Login _login)
        {

            if (_login.departmentID=="Orange")
            {
                OrderDB_testDataContext OrderDBDC = new OrderDB_testDataContext();                
            }

            if (_login.departmentID=="Tristar")
            {
                OrderDBDataContext OrderDBDC = new OrderDBDataContext();
            }

            OrderDBDC.... **<--cannot be done**
        }

        public void Insert_Member_simple
        {
            ...
        }
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the underlying schema for for both the DB are same create only one data context with two different set of connection strings.

```
if (_login.departmentID=="Orange")
{
  OrderDBDataContext OrderDBDC = new OrderDBDataContext("ConnectionString 1");
}

if (_login.departmentID=="Tristar")
{
  OrderDBDataContext OrderDBDC = new OrderDBDataContext("ConnectionString 2c");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a different connection string for each department, and use that to create the different contexts.

```
OrderDBDataContext OrderDBDC = new OrderDBDataContext(New DBConnection("DepartmentConnectionStringName"));
```